# How to calculate summation in column based on lookup of two other sets of columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table setup with 22 columns, with the following table structure (see picture/table link below):

The last column in the table is a blank column that I created, named "EuropeA" for Europe Allocation.  I want this column to be populated with ONLY country allocation %s for countries that are within Europe.

So using the example above, for first row (portnum = 1), EuropeA = Country1A (35%) only since only Germany is European (China and Mexico are obviously not).
For row 3 (portnum = 3), EuropeA = the sum of all Country1A-3A since all the countries are located in Europe.

Coming up with the list of countries that are "European" is quite easy - I just created a query that pulled up all the distinct countries from the columns 2-4, then created a list with just those countries that are european.

However, I don't know how to write the programming to calculate the summation of only columns 5-7 for those countries in my list that appear in columns 2-4.

As way of background - I am using SQL Server 2014.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you all!

[CLICK FOR TABLE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1IeH.jpg)

Comment: Your question/data are hard to follow.  Please rewrite your question to show us sample data in tabular form.  Then, also show us the expected output from the query.

Comment: I don't really understand your question but this sounds like a design issue. You should keep data in ROW rather than in COLUMNS

Comment: How do you think `SQL Server` knows that `Germany` is in `Europe` and not any other continent ? You must have another mapping table that can relate this information ?

Comment: Squirrel - yes that’s why I did a query of all possible country possibilities and manually created a list of the countries that are European. Meaning “select * In (“Belgium”, “Germany” etc”. I maintain a list of countries that I need to carve out.

Comment: Squirrel - I hear you. This is how the data gets provided from the third party data provider!

Comment: Tim - that’s why I added the table. The last column is empty - I filled it to show how I want to calculated. In row 1:  I want EuropeA to be the sum of all the countries that are designated as Europe in that row - again I maintain a list of those countries.   This is an actual data set I get from a third party provider. I’m needing to calculate this because I’m tracking how much of this investment fund is exposed to Europe (or Asia or whatever). The country and %s are Fund allocations.

Comment: Thank you all - I know it’s a wierd request. I actually have been doing this in excel for about two years on a monthly basis and it’s driving me mad!

Comment: Hi guys - I updated the example table to hopefully make it more clear.  Let me know if its still confusing?

Answer (score 0):

--Prepare list of Europiun countries
declare @Europe table(Name nvarchar(20))
INSERT INTO @Europe
VALUES('Germany'),('France'),('Portugal'),('Italy'),('Greece'),('Norway')

--Get a look of existing data

SELECT * FROM TempData

--Update EuropeA columns

UPDATE TempData SET EuropeA =Total
FROM(
    SELECT PortNum,SUM(CountryA) Total
    FROM(
        SELECT portnum, Country1 Country,Country1A CountryA  from TempData
        UNION ALL
        SELECT portnum,Country2,Country2A  from TempData
        UNION ALL
        SELECT portnum,Country3,Country3A  from TempData
    ) T
    WHERE Country IN (SELECT Name FROM @Europe)
    GROUP BY T.Portnum
) T WHERE T.Portnum=TempData.Portnum

--Get result after update

SELECT * FROM TempData